# Objective-c Set a variable to the value of another variable, keeping them independent

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I'm sure there is better terminology for my question, but the best way for me to explain it is by an example:

```
NSString* newName = [newPerson name];
```

This is not what I want, because if newPerson's name gets released at some point after this line, it ruins the newName variable. How do I set newName to the "value" of newPerson's name, effectively keeping them independent of eachother?

Comment: It depends on `newName` properties. If this assignment is within a method, it vanishes after the method finishes. If this is a variable in a class, make it `@properties (nonatomic, strong) NSString *newName;` (or `retain` instead of `strong` for non-ARC). That way the value is retained.

Comment: newName is within a method. I intend on letting it vanish once the method finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `copy`.

```
NSString *newName = [[newPerson name] copy];
```

Or if you are using MRC then you should retain the value:

```
NSString *newName = [[newPerson name] retain];
```

and then at some appropriate later time you need to call `release` on `newName`.

Comment: I would `copy` either way unless I had a very good reason not to. If it's an NSString, `copy` just retains it anyway, and if it's an NSMutableString, you just saved yourself a sneaky concurrency bug.

Comment: Excellent points to keep in mind. Though the choice of `copy` or `retain` really depends on the need of the variable.

Comment: hmm, ok, I was hoping NSString wouldn't require me to release it, and that it would just be cleaned up at the end of my function like other ints, bools, etc.

Comment: @bababooey Are you using ARC or not? If you are then it will be released for you.

Comment: @bababooey Since you choose to use MRC then you must manually do all memory management. That's the point of using MRC. Nothing is done automatically for you. That's what ARC is for. It saves you all of that extra work.

Comment: I see, sounds like I'll be converting to ARC soon. Thanks for the help